# Sort the list of objects by logical string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code snippet like this:

```
internal class Magazines
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<Magazines>();
var a_2 = new Magazines { Id = 49, Title = "SP's Aviation 10" };
var a_3 = new Magazines { Id = 50, Title = "SP's Aviation 11" };
var a_4 = new Magazines { Id = 43, Title = "SP's Aviation 100" };
var a_5 = new Magazines { Id = 48, Title = "SP's Aviation 101" };

list.AddRange(new[]{a_5, a_4, a_3, a_2});

var ordered = list.OrderBy(s => s.Title).Select(x => x.Title);

var str = string.Join(", ", ordered);
```

It is order by like this:

> SP's Aviation 10, SP's Aviation 100, SP's Aviation 101, SP's Aviation 11

But you know, it would be like this:

> SP's Aviation 10, SP's Aviation 11, SP's Aviation 100, SP's Aviation 101

How can I manage this problem?

Comment: This is called natural, not logical, sort. The *logical* way to sort strings is alphabetically, which is what happens now.

Comment: Parse the number and use it for sorting.

Comment: I've prepared the solution but question closed.